# C# application running 7zip from command line - How to stop 7zip from opening command line windows?

Tags: c#, 7zip

My C# application is running 7zip from the command line and I have the window set to hidden, but every time I have 7zip do something a command line window still pops up and disappears, I think it's the 7zip exe itself reporting the output.

Is there a way to suppress this?

```
 string strCmdText = "\"C:/Program Files/7-zip/7z.exe\" e \"" + listBox1.Items[i].ToString() + "\" -o\"" + label1.Text + "\" EMM*.zip RFE*.zip -r -y";
Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCmdText);
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You may be able to use this NuGet library to avoid needing to process via command line: https://www.nuget.org/packages/7z.NET/ This hasn't been updated in a while, but it uses the SDK from 7Zip's web site, where you can find more recent C# samples: https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Answer (score 2):

Your code open a cmd.exe with a hidden window what call 7-zip.exe with default window (visible by default).
If you can, just call directly 7-zip.exe

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:/Program Files/7-zip/7z.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "e \"" + listBox1.Items[i].ToString() + "\" -o\"" + label1.Text + "\" EMM*.zip RFE*.zip -r -y";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.Start();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```